# Read values from Dynamics CRM Lookup Entity form

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I have an entity Property which contains a field that is a lookup to the contact entity
On the Property form, I have displayed the Contact Entity using a custom form defined on the Contact entity. In my javascript code I want to read some field values from the Custom Contact form.
I have tried

`Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldname")`

`Xrm.Page.getControl('contactformname').getAttribute('fieldname')`

Neither of these work. Can someone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have created a Quick View Form for Contact that is shown on the Property form.

You can get the value of fields in a Quick View Form using [getControl().getAttribute().getValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#Anchor_3). In your case you would access the value of the field as follows, where you substitute the name of the Quick View Form and the name of the field for their real values:

```js
Xrm.Page.getControl("contactQuickFormName_contactQuickFormName_contact_fieldname")
.getAttribute()
.getValue();
```

Comment: Hi, the string you gave didn't quite work but I reckon it's close. How does one go about building this string or verifying that they have built it correctly eg from ids on the page?

Comment: "contactQuickFormName" is the name of the quick view control on your Property form. "contact" is the logical name of the entity. "fieldname" is the name of the field you want from the quick view form. Have a look at an online resource such as the following: https://mahadeomatre.blogspot.com/2015/03/access-quick-view-form-values-in.html

Comment: thanks, I've tried it and I still get Xrm.Page.getControl("contactQuickFormName_contactQuickFormName_contact_fieldname")
 as null. I there any reason you know why this would return null....some setting or property maybe?

Comment: You could use the developer console in your browser to double-check that you have the right names. The divs in your quick view form that contain fields should have the ID that you are interested in.